# Web API Controller path?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm new to Web API and followed some examples, but I cannot work out where the Controller Name is specified.

I have this in my global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Controller",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I have a Controller called TestAPI.cs

and this is the contents:

```
namespace Testing
{
    public class TestAPI : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/<controller>/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            string test= "Hello!";
            return test
        }
    }
}
```

I've only put "return test" in there as an example for Stack Overflow as it contains a lot of code.

So if I am consuming this in jQuery, what path would I use for the controller?

Comment: your controller name should be TestAPIController.cs

Comment: Controller can be located anywhere in the project but it is recommended to keep it under Controllers. The file name can be anything. Do search on entire project for class `TestAPIController`.

Comment: hmm, I seem to keep getting a 404 error message for anything I try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from the naming convention about your Web Api controller name, you also need to change the route configuration. see below:

1) Change your `TestAPI` controller like below:

```
 public class TestAPIController : ApiController
```

2) change MapHttpRoute in your Application_Start method like below:

```
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "API Controller",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
      );
```

**Note**: Don't forget also change the actual file name form `TestAPI.cs` to `TestAPIController.cs`.

Comment: Hi Lin, I have changed this as per your answer but still no luck! Gives me a 404! Thanks

Comment: hi @realtek, I think you forgot change the file name TestAPI.cs to TestAPIController.cs, see my updated answer.

Comment: Hi Lin, Yes I also did this but still no luck. Could you confirm what the file system structure should be? So does TestAPIController.cs see to be inside api/Controllers/TestAPIController.cs for example? Or does it not actually look at any filesystem? Thanks

Comment: The TestAPIController.cs file should be inside the Controller folder. If not you need to change your route.

Comment: Thank you lin! I got this working now, I just read up on http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api I didn't realise you need to drop the "Controller" bit from the client request. Its automatically added onto the end of the {controller} placeholder. It works now thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rename your controller to `TestApiController` and remove the {action} parameter from the route.

Answer (score 0):

That should just be

```
http://[yourserver]/[yourapp]/api/testapi
```

or

```
http://[yourserver]/api/testapi
```

Depending on how you set up your application

Comment: hmm, I seem to keep getting a 404 error message for anything I try?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your controller name supposed to end in "Controller" even if it's a WebApi controller?

I think

```
public class TestAPI : ApiController
```

should be

```
public class TestAPIController : ApiController
```